# C Typecasting and malloc?

Tags: c, casting, malloc, free

So I understand the use of typecasting. Making a type of variable act as another. But everytime I attempt to do so it prints a diamond lol?

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <strings.h>
    #include <windows.h>

    void loginscreen(void)
    {
         printf("\nWelcome to the login screen...\n");
         int num = 4;
         printf("%c", (char)num);
         getchar();
    }
```

Also can I get an explanation of malloc and why and how it uses typecasting.

Comment: This is really two questions ... one very specific (casting `int` to `char`) and one more broad (regarding `malloc`). To help users in the future please consider changing your question its title and its tags to reflect the simple casting issue. The web has several resources about casting the results of `malloc`.

Answer (score 2):

You are casting the number `4` to the [ASCII character `4`](http://www.ascii-code.com), which happens to be EOT (End of Transmission). This is a special character that signals the end of the input. In Unix-like systems it can be generated by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> in Windows). As this is a non-printable character, your terminal is probably displaying it as '�', the replacement character used to replace an unknown or unrepresentable character.

Addressing your other question, `malloc()` basically asks the system to give you a chunk of memory. There are plenty of wonderful resources on the web where you can find very good explanations.

Answer (score 0):

Casting (not "typecasting" doesn't make a type of variable act as another; it *converts* a value of one type to another type (or perhaps to the same type).

(Pointer conversions can be used to reinterpret an object as an object of a different type. Your code doesn't do that.)

Some conversions are implicit; others are explicit. A cast is an operator consisting of a parenthesized type name; it specifies an explicit conversion. (There's no such thing as an implicit cast.)

In your example:

```
printf("%c", (char)num);\
```

the value of `num` (which is of type `int`) is converted to type `char`. It's then immediately converted (promoted) back to type `int`, because that's the behavior when something of a type narrower than `int` is passed as an argument to a variadic function like `printf`. It would behave exactly the same way without the cast:

```
printf("%c\n", num);
```

It prints the character whose value is 4, which happens to be a non-printable control character.

You asked about `malloc`, but since there's no call to `malloc` in your code, that's (a) a separate question, and (b) it's rather vague. If you have a more specific question about `malloc`, you can post it separately. But first, I suggest reading section 7 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/), which discusses memory allocation. (In particular, you should not cast the result of `malloc`; it's unnecessary and can mask errors in some cases.)